# jenkins pipeline : how to avoid that a gerrit change verify job is superseded by a newer change

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline running, triggered by several gerrit review hooks.

e.g.
branch-v1.0
branch-v2.0

normally i receive my verifies accordingly to the result of the appropriate job run. E.g. run finished successfully with passed tests, i get the verified+1 back in my gerrit system.

My problem:

If there is running a job for verifying my gerrit change, a newer "verify job" of another change or patch, is always canceling the current running job. It doesn't matter whether the change comes from a different branch or not. Also no difference if the new change has something to do with the current one. The current running change is always superseded.

**in the console:**

*In this case the job A canceled an older B and later A was canceled by a newer job C*

```
Canceling older #3128
Waiting for builds [3126]
Canceled since #3130 got here
```

**So, does anybody know how to avoid the canceling of the current running job?**

I wanted to use the Multi-Branch pipeline (but i really do not know if this helps), but the gerrit plug-in is currently not supported by the Multi-Branch pipeline or the blue ocean project. As far as i know.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38046

There is a new gerrit plug-in in development, but there is no information when this will be available (or is 'production ready'). See the following comment in the issue.

```
lucamilanesio added a comment - 2017-08-18 15:40
```

Thanks for your support!